# JSONPath in Peewee

Tags: postgresql, peewee

Is there a way to use the Postgres JSONPath features in Peewee? I've searched the documentation and the Playhouse extension, but haven't found anything. Any resources or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special.

```
class Reg(Model):
    data = BinaryJSONField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

Reg.create(data={'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

query = Reg.select(fn.jsonb_path_query(Reg.data, '$.a[*] ? (@ >= 2)'))
for row in query.tuples():
    print(row)
# (2,)
# (3,)
# (4,)
# (5,)

query = Reg.select(fn.jsonb_path_query(Reg.data, '$.a[*] ? (@ <= $m)', json.dumps({'m': 2})))
for row in query.tuples():
    print(row)
# (0,)
# (1,)
# (2,)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this expected behavior or a work-around? query.execute() doesn't seem to work. I can get the data using query.tuples(), however query.execute() returns an object that when iterated over has only None objects. (However, this return object does have the correct number of iterable objects - though they are all None)

Comment: You'll need to alias the json path expression to access it via a model instance. See the peewee docs on sql functions.